# Jquery :: How can I delete content of div <div>...<li>sdsds</li>.../div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I delete content of div with jquery?

example of div id container

**input**:

```
<div id="container">
<h1>sdsdsdsd</h1>
dsdsdsdsds
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
dsfdfsd
</div>
```

**output:**

```
<div id="container">   
 </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/), like this:

```
$("#container").empty();
```

[You can give it a test here](http://jsfiddle.net/xTppu/), it's important to use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) or [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) when you have events/data bound to any descendants inside what you're clearing...otherwise you're leaking memory that won't be cleaned up.

Comment: ...because attached `event handlers` and jQuery `.data()` hash entrys are not removed... :)

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#container").empty()
```

http://api.jquery.com/empty/